# JS rubber band effect, anybody?

Tags: javascript, webkit, mobile-safari

Given a `div "square"`
and given I already have a `touchmove` function on that div and I can detect the position X in real time:

how can I implement the rubber band effect?

I mean: tap and drag to the left until the resistance reach the limit and if ou release the finger the `square div` goes back to its initial position with an easing animation

there is a simple math for that? or a plugin?

UPDATE

w/o jquery would be better if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store its original position somewhere.

Then on the dragend event:

```
$(this).animate({
    top: original_top,
    left: original_left
}, 'slow');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/T8zYt/**

Full code (with jQuery `draggable`):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.rubber = function(resist) {

        var self = this,
            position = $(this).position(),
            selfPos = {
                top: position.top,
                left: position.left,
                maxTop: resist + position.top,
                maxLeft: resist + position.left,
                minTop: resist - position.top,
                minLeft: resist - position.left
            };
        self.draggable({
            drag: function() {
                var position = $(this).position(), width = $(this).width(),  height = $(this).height();
                if (position.left > selfPos.maxLeft || (position.left - width)  < selfPos.minLeft || position.top > selfPos.maxTop || (position.top - height) < selfPos.minTop) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            stop: function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: selfPos.top,
                    left: selfPos.left
                }, 'slow');
            }
        })

    };
})(jQuery)

$('selector').rubber(10);​
```

Comment: There's no resistance or elasticity in your example. This is just slow animation.

Comment: @j08691 I also added a jsFiddle Demo

Comment: Your example is OK, but I imagine that the OP is looking for something with an effect closer to this: http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

Comment: @j08691 you know what happens when you **assume**... The OP just stated `square` not a list.

Comment: I'm not referring to the shape vs. list, I'm referring to the resistance, rubber-like effect.

Comment: @j08691 haha. well i **never** said it was perfect ^_^ just a way to get started. im sure other `animate` effects would be better.

Comment: @j08691 you could play around with the tension: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/T8zYt/5/

Comment: the iScroll example is perfect, but as far as i know he uses a different way of scrolling where i'm involved in dragging.
As far as dragging I would use any jquery UI, I already have the value pageX.. my question is more what can I do starting there with the x value to create a rubber fx

Comment: @Francesco did you look at my fiddle?